# Cant find "Mono.Android" in remote branch xamarin forms project

Tags: git, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I made a cross-platform application with visual studio 2019 community and xamarin forms, then I added GIT as a source code control and I uploaded it to my GitHub repositorie. All the project development was programmed in my personal pc and tested on my mobile device.

I installed VS 2019 Community in other PC and added GIT as a source code as well and pull the repositorie of my cross-platform application in that PC. Now the problem im having is that VS cant find the "Mono.Android" reference. Right now i cant build or deploy/debug the app on my movile device.

I checked for the specific files and noticed that some were missing in the project folder hosted in the other PC. I tried to fix this by copying those files into my drive and paste it in the specific folders of the other project, then re-build the project but it did not work.

I add some screen shots of the missing files:

[image: -Solution (Personal PC)]

[image: -Solution (Other PC)]

[image: -Folder of the solution (Personal PC)]

[image: -Specific folder (Personal PC)]

[image: -Specific folder (Other PC)]

[image: -Warning (Still showing before and after re-build the solution in the other PC)]

translation: Cannot resolve this reference. "Mono.Android" is not assembled. Check if the assembly exist in the disk.

Comment: Shared project is not supposed to have reference to Mono.Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now (05-07-2021) I solved the issue.

[Visual Studio 2019 Start Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn82d.png)

When I try to clone my github repositorie from Visual Studio 2019 (VS2019) there are two options:

-Clone the repository by **giving the URL**.

-Clone the repository by **browse thru all your GitHub repositories**.

[Clone repository options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjylS.png)

The problem I had was that by cloning the repository selecting the second option some files where missing (just how I explained previously).

if I select the first option (**clone by giving the URL**) the files that were one missing are now downloaded. It seems to work!!!

Specific folder in my personal PC
[-Specific folder (Personal PC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUqWB.png)

Specific folder in other PC (Trying to clone repos by browsing thru my GitRepos)
[-Specific folder (Other PC - Not Solved)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spj6g.png)

Specific folder in other PC (Trying to clone repos by giving the GitRepos URL)
[Specific folder (Other PC - Solved)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oioCx.png)

Solution Explorer after cloning
[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDDkp.png)